# MPAndroidChart: Horizontal Bar Chart in combined chart

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, charts

is it possible to add hoizontal bar chart to a combined chart in mpandroid chart library. for example I want to implement somthing like this:[image]

The entry data of HorizontalBarChart and BarChart are the same. So, I dont know how to draw horizontal bar chart in combined chart.